# Are Okta Provisioning Agent SDK and Java SDK same?

Tags: okta, okta-api

I can see two terms (i.e. Okta Provisioning Agent SDK, and Java SDK) continuously when I am browsing OKTA documents.Are Okta Provisioning Agent SDK and Java SDK same? I can find a link to download Java SDK. However, I am not able to find download link for Okta Provisioning Agent SDK. Can someone please provide me the download link for Okta Provisioning Agent SDK?

Answer (score 1):

These are two different SDKs.

The Java SDK is for accessing the REST APIs offered by the Okta Platform.

The Okta On-Premises Provisioning Framework SDK is to enable various endpoints so that Okta can manage the users and groups in that endpoint. This is similar to a provisioning connector.  The download for the SDK will be available in your Okta organization under the Downloads section. Please reach out to Okta Support/Account team to investigate this option.